# Problem running finplot overlay on pyside2. But in pyqt5 it works

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

Problem running finplot overlay on pyside2.
There is no error message either.
The program is automatically closed with no response.

But in pyqt5 it works without problems.

Is there any way to solve it in pyside2?

[running pyside2 gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezykr.gif)

[running pyqt5 gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sodQ.gif)

Below is the source code.

```
import sys 
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
# from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import finplot as fplt
import pyupbit

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        widget= QGraphicsView()
        layout = QGridLayout(widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.resize(800, 300)
        ax = fplt.create_plot_widget(widget, init_zoom_periods=100)           
        widget.axs = [ax]                                       
        layout.addWidget(ax.ax_widget, 0, 0)                    
        df = pyupbit.get_ohlcv("KRW-BTC")
        df.rename(columns={'open': "Open", "high": "High", "low": "Low", "close":"Close"}, inplace=True)
        fplt.autoviewrestore()
        fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']])
        fplt.volume_ocv(df[['Open', 'Close', 'volume']], ax=ax.overlay()) 
        fplt.show(qt_exec=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Interesting. I poked around a bit, but couldn't make much sense of it. What is the purpose of using pyside instead of pyqt? Is it for licensing reasons?

Comment: While proceeding with pyside2 due to a license problem
I found a bug.